# How to properly generate URL with more then one argument

Tags: codeigniter, google-maps

How to generate URL in my current code, so I can pass the values to my directions function.

This is my code for displaying markers on map for each company:

```
$n = 0;
   foreach ($firm as $f) {
     if ($f->active == 1 && in_array($f->skd_n, $dejavnost) && $f->lat != 0) {
          $lat_f = $f->lat;
          $lng_f = $f->lng;
          $distance = (($this->distance($lat, $lng, $lat_f, $lng_f)) * 1000);
             if ($distance <= $rad && $n <= 199) {
                $marker = array();
                $marker['position'] = "$lat_f, $lng_f";
                  if ($f->phone != 0) {
                     $marker['infowindow_content'] = '<div class="info_window">' . "$f->title" . '<br/>' .
                     '<div class="pin_icon"></div>' .
                     "$f->address" . '<br/>' .
                     '<div class="phone_icon"></div>' .
                     "$f->phone" . '<br/>' .
                     //generate URL with 4 arguments
                     '<a href="?????">DIRECTION</a>' .
                     '</div><br/>';      
                  }else{
                     $marker['infowindow_content'] = '<div class="info_window">' . "$f->title" . '<br/>' .
                     '<div class="pin_icon"></div>' .
                     "$f->address" . '</div>';
                  }
                 $marker['animation'] = 'DROP';
                 $marker['zIndex'] = '0';
                 $marker['icon'] = '../images/pin-map-red.png';
                 $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
                 $n++;
              }
       }
   }
```

I want to add anchor to next function, where question marks are and use variables (coordinates) as arguments:

```
function direction($lat, $lng, $lat_f, $lng_f){
   $config['places'] = TRUE;
   $config['placesAutocompleteInputID'] = 'event_location';
   $config['placesAutocompleteBoundsMap'] = TRUE;
   $config['zoom'] = 'auto';
   $config['center'] = 'auto';
   $config['directions'] = TRUE;
   $config['directionsStart'] = "$lat, $lng";
   $config['directionsEnd'] = "$lat_f, $lng_f";
   $config['directionsDivID'] = 'directions';
   $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);
   $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
   $this->load->view('header', $data);
   $this->load->view('domov_view', $data);
   $this->load->view('footer');
```

}

How can I use values in second function (direction) from first?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the arguments in url and fetch them inside your direction method via $_GET method

Example:
You could generate link like that

```
<a href="site_url()."direction"."?lat=".$lat."&lng=".$lng."&lat_f=".$lat_f."&lng_f=".$lng_f">DIRECTION</a>
```

So your function would look like this:

```
$n = 0;
foreach ($firm as $f) {
    if ($f->active == 1 && in_array($f->skd_n, $dejavnost) && $f->lat != 0) {
        $lat_f = $f->lat;
        $lng_f = $f->lng;
        $distance = (($this->distance($lat, $lng, $lat_f, $lng_f)) * 1000);
        if ($distance <= $rad && $n <= 199) {
            $marker = array();
            $marker['position'] = "$lat_f, $lng_f";
            if ($f->phone != 0) {
                $marker['infowindow_content'] = '<div class="info_window">' . "$f->title" . '<br/>' .
                '<div class="pin_icon"></div>' .
                "$f->address" . '<br/>' .
                '<div class="phone_icon"></div>' .
                "$f->phone" . '<br/>' .
                '<a href="'.site_url()."direction"."?lat=".$lat."&lng=".$lng."&lat_f=".$lat_f."&lng_f=".$lng_f.'">DIRECTION</a>' .
                '</div><br/>';
            }else{
                $marker['infowindow_content'] = '<div class="info_window">' . "$f->title" . '<br/>' .
                '<div class="pin_icon"></div>' .
                "$f->address" . '</div>';
            }
            $marker['animation'] = 'DROP';
            $marker['zIndex'] = '0';
            $marker['icon'] = '../images/pin-map-red.png';
            $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
            $n++;
        }
    }
}
```

And fetch them this way in directions function

```
function direction(){
   $lat = $this->input->get('lat');
   $lng = $this->input->get('lng');
   $lat_f = $this->input->get('lat_f');
   $lng_f = $this->input->get('lng_f');
   $config['places'] = TRUE;
   $config['placesAutocompleteInputID'] = 'event_location';
   $config['placesAutocompleteBoundsMap'] = TRUE;
   $config['zoom'] = 'auto';
   $config['center'] = 'auto';
   $config['directions'] = TRUE;
   $config['directionsStart'] = "$lat, $lng";
   $config['directionsEnd'] = "$lat_f, $lng_f";
   $config['directionsDivID'] = 'directions';
   $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);
   $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
   $this->load->view('header', $data);
   $this->load->view('domov_view', $data);
   $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

**P.S.:** If you are sending langitude and longitude via url you will probably have problems with sending disallowed chars via url (dot(.)).
You can configure allowed url chars in config file

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_=+-'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend url helper. Add function some:

```
create_url('controller/action', [
    'getParam1' => 'value1',
    'getParam2' => 'value2',
    'getParam3' => 'value3',
]);
```

And it generate **http://base.url/controller/action?getParam1=value&getParam2=value2&getParam3=value3**

or use

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/uri.html

create link $this->uri->assoc_to_uri()

parse link $this->uri->uri_to_assoc()